# Algorithms for Tracking moving objects with a moving camera

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, image-segmentation, feature-extraction, motion-detection

I'm trying to develop an algorithm for real time tracking moving objects with a single moving camera setup as a project, in OpenCV (C++).

My basic objectives are

- Detect motion in an (initially) static frame
- Track that moving object (camera to follow that object)

Here is what I have tried already

- Salient motion detection using temporal differencing and Optical Flow. (does not compensate for a  moving camera)
- KLT based feature tracking, but I was not able to segment the moving object features (moving object features got mixed with other trackable features in the image)
- Mean shift based tracking (required initialization and is a bit computationally expensive)

I'm now trying to look into the following methods

- Histogram of Gradients.
- Algorithms that implement camera motion parameters.

Any advice on which direction should I proceed forward to acheive my objective.

Comment: For tracking you could look at this: http://blogs.oregonstate.edu/hess/code/particles/

Comment: How can KLT features of object and background get mixed? If you (initially) know where the moving object is, just ignore/delete other features?? I would try probabilistic tracking (e.g. particle filtering) and maybe add some camera movement to the object state.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by object state? I'm guessing it means the feature points that describe a moving object

@Erik ... thank you. I didn't know of particle filters before this

Comment: no no, in probabilistic tracking you try to track the "state" of the object. Often it is the position (2D or 3D) and the velocity (2D or 3D) of the object. Have a look at: http://ttic.uchicago.edu/~rurtasun/courses/CV/lecture10.pdf but beware that those probabilistic tracking techniques have some mathematical background you should understand if you want to implement that. This is a sample video of particle filtering in action: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O1FZyWz_yj4

Comment: this is the work of the video in detail, maybe you can use some of this stuff: http://kth.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:535572/FULLTEXT01.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Type: 'zdenek kalal predator' to google.com and watch the videos, read the papers that came up. I think it will give you a lot of insight.

Comment: Will it possible to implement TLD in about 5 weeks (the time I have remaining)?

Comment: Well, it depends on your performance.. It is open source and coded in matlab, some are mex functions (c codes). I can implement it in 5 weeks, can you? :)

Comment: I think it has been ported to OpenCV...

http://sourceforge.net/projects/qopentld/files/